# Определение столкновений в Android

Tags: разработка-игр, android, java

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу отловить столкновение двух прямоугольников. Пытался сделать это при помощи `intersects()`, но оно требует два прямоугольника внутри метода, а мне нужно отловить только столкновение с одним прямоугольником. Вот что я пишу:

```
  Iterator<Enemy> i = enemy.iterator();
          while(i.hasNext()) {
              Enemy e = i.next();
              if(((Ball) ball).getRect().intersects((e.getRect())))
              {
                  i.remove();
              }
          }
```

Чего оно хочет не знаю, должно работать, в уроках на ютубе видел что там применяется один объект и все было нормально... В чем трабла?

**UPDATE:**

Значит так. `Enemy` и `Ball` - это два класса; балл - это пуля, которая должна убивать врага, соответственно, энеми - это враг, которого должен убивать бал. Мне нужно отловить столкновение этих двух объектов, отлавливать пытаюсь при помощи `intersects`, который требует иметь два прямоугольника, хотя в видеоуроке, который я смотрел, повествователь туториала используется всего лишь один объект класса, второй используется для вызова интерсекта, как в моем примере кода. Вот и вопрос, чем отличается его интерсект от моего?
Вот его урок [Пишем 2D игру на java - Часть 7.](http://youtu.be/CD2hmGu8_NQ?t=8m34s)

Ошибка которую мне выдает когда я начинаю компилировать

> The method intersects(Rect, Rect) in the type Rect is not applicable for the arguments (Rect)

**UPDATE 2:**

Нашел я способ который решает мою проблему, возможно кому нибудь пригодится. Я почти полностью видоизменил код, вот как он выглядит:

```
private void testCollision() {
        Iterator<Enemy> i = enemy.iterator();
        Iterator<Ball> b = ball.iterator();

          while(i.hasNext() && b.hasNext()) {
              Enemy enemies = i.next();
              Ball balls = b.next();

              if (Math.abs(balls.x - enemies.x) <= (balls.width + enemies.width) / 2f
                      && Math.abs(balls.y - enemies.y) <= (balls.height + enemies.height) / 2f) {
                        i.remove();
                        b.remove();
              }
          }
    }
```

balls.x - enemies.x - центральная граница нашего объекта.

**UPDATE 3:**

Снова открываю тему так как у меня возникла проблема,

> "нужно вернуть итератор снова на
> первый элемент, потому что он уже
> загнан предыдущим проходом на
> последний и hasNext() ивозвращает
> false."

Это цитата одного человека который пытался мне объяснить как исправить ошибку, но так и не смог объяснить. Может кто-то сможет мне сказать как это сделать? Код я использую тот же.

После прочтения этой цитаты несколько раз - у меня сломался мозг

Comment: задумайтесь над своим вопросом: вот какую полезную информацию он несет для человека который не знает что вы делаете и что пытаетесь сделать:  
1) вам надо отловить столкновение 2-х прямоугольников  
2) вам не надо отловить столкновение 2-х прямоугольников, но вам надо отловить столкновение 1-го прямоугольника с непонятно чем  
3) у вас есть классы/нитерфейсы Enemy и Ball и мы не знаем что они собой представляют

если подумать логически то столкновение 2х прямоугольников означает что хотя бы 1 точка прямоугольника А лежит на одной из сторон прямоугольника Б или наоборот.

Comment: Да, @dajver, если уж говорить о вопросе, то надо указывать **что именно не работает**.

1. не компилится *или*

2. вбрасывает exception *или*

3. ожидаю, что i.remove выполнится N раз, а он вызывается M раз.

4. и т.п.

Что-то в таком духе.

Comment: ну же народ!!!

Comment: больше кода

Comment: не понял к чему Вы это написали? Выложить весь код игры?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#intersects(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D)
может вам нужен этот метод?

Comment: В том то и дело что в обычной java этот метод есть, а в sdk android - нет....

Comment: ну, единственное что я могу вам сказать, ищите метод с именем intersect, или еще раз внимательно просмотрите этот видеоурок, может там используется сторонняя библиотека

Comment: этот урок для java, а я пишу под андроид, и я уже понял что придется писать свой метод который будет отлавливать столкновения

Comment: 2 @dajver: я еще вы должны были понять - чем больше информации вы предоставите, тем больше шансов получить быстрый ответ! удачи:)

Comment: ну ответа я точно тут не получил)

Comment: @dajver, как ответа не получили ? Разве я неправильно подсказал Rect.intersects(...) ?

Comment: Правильно но этот метод не работает в моем случае, по этому как бы не правильный))) Но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@dajver](/users/4821/dajver)](/users/4821/dajver), Сами пишете что ошибка при компиляции :

```
The method intersects(Rect, Rect) in the type Rect is not applicable for the arguments (Rect)
```

Это значит, что метод Rect.intersects() **хочет два** аргемента (оба типа Rect).

Видимо надо написать (если ищем пересечение прямоугольной пули с прямоугольным врагом):

```
if( ((Ball)ball).getRect().intersects(e.getRect(),((Ball)ball).getRect()) ) {
    i.remove();
    break; // это если одна пуля может уложить только одного врага
}
```

Comment: Если пишу как Вы сказали то у меня выдает The static method intersects(Rect, Rect) from the type Rect should be accessed in a static way

Comment: Ага ..., он статический. Тогда попробуйте

    while (...) {
        ...
        Rect ballr = (Ball)ball.getRect();
        if (Rect.intersects(balr,e.getRect())) {
           ...
        }
     }

Answer (score 2):

вы бы ошибку выложили, скорее всего у ball нету метода getRect.

*продолжая читать мысли*: сделайте этот метод в Ball, возвращая прямоугольник описанного ball или вписанного.

---

осмелюсь предположить что x, y это центр ball. А Rect это координаты верхней левой и  правой нижней точек

следовательно должно быть чтото типа:

```
public Rect getRect()
{
    new Rect(x - width/2, y - height / 2, x + width/2, y + height / 2)
}
```

Comment: есть

 public Rect getRect()
 {
     return new Rect(x, y, 27, 40);
 }

Comment: Так что не работает, в while() валится ?

Comment: а вот ошибки нет, все работает как нужно, только не сталкивается ничего

Comment: *опять же, одевая телепатический шлем*

обновляю  ответ.

Comment: @dajver, i.remove() отрабатывает (и по Вашему нужное количество раз) ?

Comment: не понял вашего вопроса